# Google PubSub listener freezing

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got an issue with Google PubSub Node.js listener freezing using pull.

I use the following flow:

```
1. PubSub client is created,
2. Subscription is fetched from the specified topic
3. Listeners are attached to "message" and "error" events.
```

At first it pulls around ~500 messages and acknowledges them, but after that it just hangs, with > 1000 messages in the queue. I've tried periodically reiniting the listeners (`removeListener/on`), but it only fetches few messages. After restarting the app, it pulls ~500 and the same happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking your [FlowControl](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L23) setup, it might be limiting the number and the rate at which your subscriber receives messages. Additionally, if you do not ack or nack the messages that you’ve received, they will count toward the total number of outstanding messages. Once the [maxMessages](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L35) limit is reached, the subscriber will not receive anymore messages until the outstanding messages are either acked or nacked (or expired and will eventually be redelievered after [maxExtension](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/3388fb735b87a8ac817c604cf777a5d8d4e7f833/src/lease-manager.ts#L33) period).

For more information: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#subscriber-flow-control-nodejs